# Mongodb Full text search, get the matched string in the document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, full-text-search

I am trying to implement FTS feature with node and mongdodb backend. In the search result, I would also like to project a new field, i.e the matched string in the document. This would give it a google like feel. Has anyone got ideas on this without having write lots of own custom functions?

The schema looks like this

```
var version = new mongoose.Schema({     
    name:   String,     
    owner: String, 
    reviewer: String,
    date_of_modification: Date,
    comments:           String,             
    hints: [String],
    global:   Boolean,      
    **content:  { type: [String], index: true }**
    version_no: Number,                 
});


var artifactSchema= new mongoose.Schema({

    pid :   String,
    trashed :  Boolean,
    baseline : Number,
    versions : [version],                   
});
```

I would like to create an index on the content field of Version model.

Comment: Please show us your intended document structure and the expected results. Actually, it should be pretty easy using aggregations, but in order to make the answer meaningful, please give a concrete example.

Comment: This sort of metadata from the text search result is not currently available. Nor is there an effective way to interrogate the response on the server in order to "highlight" your search terms in the response, without resorting to a pretty nasty mapReduce method of processing in code, which is not what you want. You would be better off using an external text search engine for this. And the aggregation framework lacks the necessary operators to match strings as @MarkusWMahlberg suggests, so that would not be an option.

Comment: @NeilLunn: The $regex in an early $match phase would work! and for highlighting a string concatenation in a project phase could be used. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg But how to you determine which strings from the search are the matches and "highlight" them in an aggregation pipeline? There is no logical equivalent, so it can't be done. I don't think mapReduce is suited either even though you could do this in JavaScript with a regex match and match variables. External solutions are better aimed at this than MongoDB presently is and/or is likely to be in the future. Solr/ElasticSearch etc etc all do this OOTB

Comment: I figured it would get messy with Mongodb. As it is a prototype project in initial phase, I put in a elasticDB storing the content field. Elasticdb provides elasticSearch with highlighting capability which is working quite well.

Answer (score -1):

I know its a little late but recently I did it with MEAN+angucomplete
AngularJS Query e.g. http://localhost:8080/api/search?s=
Express Query

```
router.route('/search')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Dept.aggregate(
            { $match : { 'Product.name' : new RegExp(query, 'gi') } },
            { $project : { name : 1, _id : 1,  'Product.name' : 1, 'Product._id' : 1} },
            { $unwind : "$Product" },
            { $group : {
                _id : "$_id",
                Category : { $addToSet : "$name"},
                Product : { $push : "$Product"}
            }}
        )
    });
```

Angucomplete Markup

```
<div angucomplete-alt id="depts"
    placeholder="Click Here to Search across Whole Store"
    pause="300" 
    selected-object="selectedDepts" 
    remote-url="http://localhost:8080/api/search?s="
    remote-url-data-field="Departments"
    remote-url-response-formatter="responseFormatted"     
    search-fields="name"
    title-field="name"
    minlength="1"
    maxlength="20"
    description-field="description"
    override-suggestions="true" 
    match-class="highlight"
    autocapitalize="on" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" 
    input-class="form-control form-control-small"
    class="col-lg-8"
    ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z]+$/"
    docs-search-input-focus
>
</div>
```